# Read csv files that contain/without certain character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have several csv files in a same folder, some contain the character '^' and some don't, I read them as df in the way below:

```
def readfile(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['ticker'] = f.split('.')[0].strip('^')
    return df
```

And now I want to define two functions likewise, but:

1. `readfile1(f)` such that it only reads files that **doesn't contain ^**, and return the df with the ticker as the file name.
2. `readfile2(f)` such that it only reads files that **contain ^**, and return the df with the ticker as the file name without the ^

Can I do that by making some changes on `readfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try the following code:

```
def readfile(f):
   df = pd.read_csv(f)
   if '^' in f:
       df['ticker'] = f.split('.')[0].strip('^')
   else:
       df['ticker'] = f
   return df
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want two separate df's, one contains the csvs with ^, another contains the csvs without ^

Comment: This will return you in every run one df with the file name as column. You should call the function with for each filename.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `ticker` and once you encounter `^` break the loop and use `readfile2` otherwise use `readfile1`